# Why is subjunctive used in: "no es que haya tardado"

Tags: subjuntivo

In *Déjame Que Te Cuente* by Jorge Bucay, why would the subjunctive be used when he says "haya tardado"?

> -Sí, claro. ¿Qué te ha pasado? ¿Por qué has tardado tanto? ¿Te has perdido?
>
> -No, no es que haya tardado. No he querido llamar al timbre para no molestar, por si estaba atendiendo a alguien...

Can any event that didn't happen use subjunctive and would the meaning be identical if the indicative was used?

I found another example where an event that didn't happen uses the subjunctive (from Historia de un Gaviota by Luis Sepúlveda):
"En ninguna parte está escrito que los gatos entren gratis."

Answer (score 5):

When you say *es que…*, you are stating a reality: the action *he tardado* actually happened.  On the other hand, when you say *no es que…*, you are now stating something to not be the case, and the action *haya tardado* is not a true statement.

You could use indicative by simply moving the negative to the subordinate clause: *es que no he tardado* (now we state the reality that we were *not* late), but obviously that doesn't quite work in the context of the conversation.

Comment: It seems weird to me because the event definitely didn't happen. Usually it seems like the subjunctive is used when there is a hypothetical situation being imagined under alternate conditions. Not telling someone something wasn't the case.

Comment: "Por qué no haya usado Bucay el modo indicativo en este caso?". Would that not seem odd to native speakers because he definitely did not use the indicative...

Comment: @user135711 `¿Por qué no haya usado Bucay el modo indicativo en este caso?` is incorrect, because it is not a subordinate, you must use indicative in this case.

Comment: I don't find anything odd about the construction. I could have equally said: *No, no es que tardé* (my dialect tends to use simple rather than compound tenses). Or simply *No tardé*, with some emphasis on the verb so as to focus on the fact that *tardar* is precisely not what I did.

Comment: There are many uses for subjunctive, not all of them are for hypothetical situations.  You could simple state "I didn't arrive late" by saying "no he tardado".  Prefixing with "es que no he tardado" just explains that the reality is X.  X is guaranteed true.  When we say "No es que X", X is quite the opposite: it's guaranteed to be false, despite not having a negative in it.  The opposite happens with the verb "dudar".  "Dudo que X" means X likely isn't true (and uses subj), but "No dudo que X" means X is true (and uses ind)

Comment: @pablodf76 interesante, entonces para ti *no es que* funciona algo como *no creo que* para decidir entre subjuntivo e indicativo?  ¿O usarías casi siempre indicativo con el pretérito indefinido?

Comment: @guifa Yo no diría nunca *No creo que tardé* sino *No creo que haya tardado* o *No creo haber tardado*. Y *no es que* me suena bien con subjuntivo o con indicativo, aunque el indicativo me suena más coloquial. Mi preferencia por el pretérito indefinido la indiqué porque sé que en España se usa mucho más el compuesto. Tengo que pensar en todo esto y prestar atención a cómo hablo. :P

Comment: @pablodf76 Coincido contigo (o sea, con vos) en que "No creo que tardé" se usa coloquialmente por estas latitudes. No obstante, creo que el pretérito perfecto compuesto del subjuntivo es más seguro, sobre todo si el sujeto de la subordinada no coincide con el principal: ?No creo que tardó (mejor: No creo que (él/ella) haya tardado), ¿estás de acuerdo?

Comment: @Gustavson Lo que yo dije es que no usaría nunca "No creo que tardé", aunque sí diga "No es que tardé". Con *creer* va el tiempo compuesto y el modo subjuntivo (porque tampoco me suena decir "No creo que tardase").

Comment: @pablodf76 ¡Entendido! ¡Perdón por la confusión!

Answer (score 3):

In subordinate sentences with main sentence being impersonal:

- if the *main sentence is affirmative*, the **subordinate** sentence must be **indicative**
- if the *main sentence is negative* or *interrogative*, the **subordinate** sentence must be **subjunctive**.

Examples:

> Es cierto que tengo un buen trabajo
>
> No es cierto que tenga un buen trabajo

Comment: Here, there is a specific grammar rule being used. The subject of the subordinate clause doesn't exist. That rule doesn't apply in my example though...

Comment: @user135711 I'm not sure of your comment, `no es que haya tardado` has `yo` as elliptic subject, it is the same as `no es que yo haya tardado`, but the subject is usually omitted.

Comment: What I mean is the grammar rule you cite applies when the subject doesn't actually exist. Here, the subject does exist so that rule doesn't apply.

Comment: @user135711 Sorry about my English, I update the answer trying to be more clear

Comment: @user135711 I agree with you that the constructions are not the same: in yours, "que no hayas tardado" is the complement of a tacit subject (perhaps "the fact"), and the structure is used to emphasize the whole sentence (similar to English cleft sentences starting with "It's not that..."/"It's that...."), and in a sentence like: *No conozco a nadie que haya tardado tanto*, "que haya tardado tanto" is a relative clause. However, I agree with greuze that both constructions share the subordinate clause, the negative outside the subordinate and the subjunctive, and that makes them similar in a way

Comment: @greuze Notice that the main sentence does not need to be impersonal for the subjunctive to be used in the subordinate. I realize you made an effort to find a sentence as similar as possible to the original one (good for you), but the same rule would apply if we had a personal construction in the main clause: Creo que tengo un buen trabajo / No creo que tenga un buen trabajo.

Comment: +1 The first step is to understand that "no es que " equals "no es verdad que" or "no es cierto que". And, yes,the main sentence "No es (verdad) que..." is impersonal. The rules are quite complicated, though http://hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/Subjuntivo%20en%20subordinadas%20sustantivas.htm

Comment: @leonbloy Good find! Anyway, I don't think "No es que" is always equivalent to "No es cierto/verdad que". "No es que" may be merely emphatic, while the other structures (which are not impersonal because the subject is the extraposed "que"- clause) express the speaker's opinion about the untruthfulness of the statement that follows.